# What features does q /KDB provide for HFT use?

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, trading, high-frequency

It appears `q/KDB` is being using for Time series analysis for `HFT`. 
What are some of the advantages of using `q/KDB` for `HFT` time series over other regular time series.

Does it provide for multivariate statistical testing etc done normally on time series?

Does it provide easy to use facilities for Statistical Arb and technical analysis?

Are there any free versions of `q/KDB` to use and learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDB is a column oriented database and is optimized for time series. As far as I know there are no libraries available for statistical testing and you pretty much have to write things on your own.

This page has tutorials
http://code.kx.com/wiki/Main_Page

You can download the free version from here
http://kx.com/software-download.php

The most popular book is below
[http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/contents](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB%3aQforMortals2/contents)

Comment: Is there a good reference for kind of analysis done using this? Obviously, tick level data has varying time intervals rendering normal analysis useless.

Comment: Some of the time series analysis books will have chapters addressing "High Frequency". You may want to start with ACD models